# Wifite not working properly

Tags: wireless

Each time I try to use [Wifite](https://tools.kali.org/wireless-attacks/wifite) on my Ubuntu 18.04, I get this message:

```
     [+] 1 target selected.

 [0:08:20] starting wpa handshake capture on "software-lab"
 [0:08:18] new client found: 94:39:E5:E7:CA:CB                         
 [0:08:05] listening for handshake...                     
 [0:00:15] handshake captured! saved as "hs/softwarelab_F0-9F-C2-DD-74-50.cap"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/wifite", line 3462, in <module>
    engine.Start()
  File "/usr/bin/wifite", line 1391, in Start
    if wpa_attack.RunAttack():
  File "/usr/bin/wifite", line 2077, in RunAttack
    self.wpa_get_handshake()
  File "/usr/bin/wifite", line 2219, in wpa_get_handshake
    if self.RUN_CONFIG.WPA_STRIP_HANDSHAKE: self.strip_handshake(save_as)
  File "/usr/bin/wifite", line 2481, in strip_handshake
    rename(capfile + '.temp', output_file)
  File "/usr/bin/wifite", line 1582, in rename
    os.rename(old, new)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: its version 18.04

Comment: You can run Wifite with a number of different arguments. Would you be able to edit your answer to specify what command you're running? Also, what version of Wifite are you running and how are you running it?

Comment: Am new with Wifite, and am just starting to know how to use it. i do use Wifiphisher but i just wanted to expand my knowledge. As for the version, its v1.0

Answer (score 1):

According to their Git page;

Wifite is designed specifically for the latest version of Kali Linux. ParrotSec is also supported. I have been unsuccessful getting it working in Ubuntu, but flawless in Kali. Perhaps a VirtualBox of Kali will eliminate the issues you are having, as well as the subsequent tools that you will be using after.

Comment: Ok, i will give Kali a try but would still love to use it on ubuntu